# What is the logic behind The order of DockPanel children elements

Tags: wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls, dockpanel

I know the order of `DockPanel` children elements matters. I've read somewhere that layout of a child is determined based on the available space left after all previous children have already been positioned. So for example for this piece of code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="20" Content="MyButton"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CarList.Items}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

I'm getting a result like picture below where my Button is docked to the **bottom** as expected:

[image]

Now if I change the order of children elements like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CarList.Items}"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="20" Content="MyButton"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The layout gets weired:

[image]

Regardless of the fact that my Button uses the available space left, shouldn't at least it gets docked to the bottom of this space?

Comment: Here is an [excellent tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDockPanel.aspx) on the `DockPanel`. Enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not considering the `DockPanel` [LastChildFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill(v=vs.110).aspx) property. As you can read:

> true  if the last child element stretches to fill the remaining space;
>   otherwise false. The default value is true.

Anyway you can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/dockpanel/).

Comment: Thats true, I guess I got confused because I set `Height` for my Button. thanks.